# Uncaught ReferenceError - cucumber node js

Tags: javascript, cucumber

In a first javascript file I am able to get a value `result_0`

```
"use strict" ;
const { Builder, By, Capabilities, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { Given, When, Then, AfterAll } = require('cucumber');

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
var fs = require('fs');

class HomePage {

  async capture(){
    result_0 = await (await driver.findElement(By.id('text-test'))).getText();
  }

}

module.exports = new HomePage ();
```

If I try to use the `result_0` value in another javascript file I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError : result_0 is not defined

for instance to carry out an assert
`assert.equal( result_0,result);`

Answer (score 0):

you either need to add a `var` in front of `result_0` your function

```
async capture(){
  var result_0 = await (await driver.findElement(By.id('text-test'))).getText();
}
```

or define `result_0` somewhere

```
"use strict" ;
const { Builder, By, Capabilities, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');
const { Given, When, Then, AfterAll } = require('cucumber');
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
var fs = require('fs');
var result_0 = ''; // here

class HomePage {
  async capture(){
    result_0 = await (await driver.findElement(By.id('text-test'))).getText();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @rhavelka for your answer. I tried both but it didn't work. I need to do this because I am striving to get used to the Page Model Object Pattern. I agree with you that the value must be defined or stored somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
class HomePage {

  async capture(){
    result_0 = await (await driver.findElement(By.id('text-test'))).getText();
  }
   return result_0 ; 

}
```

Comment: A bit of explanation about how this fixed it would make this better. Right now this is "spot-the-difference"

Comment: Sure, the only thing I have done is using the "return" method so that  the value can be read and used  in the other module. I have been told they are many techniques to do that.